# Let $L$ be the splitting field of the polynomial $ f$ over $K$, Prove that if $n!=[L:K]$, the polynomial is irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

Let $K$ be a field and $f \in K[x]$ be a non zero polynomial of degree $n$. Let $L$ be the splitting field of $f$ over $K$.

Prove  that $[L:K]$ divides $n!$  - I already proved this.

Now I am stuck at this:

**Prove that if $n!=[L:K]$, the polynomial is irreducible.**

I have no idea how to proceed, although I think I should go by induction, not sure how to actually carry it out.

Comment: I think it's easiest to show the contrapositive: if $f$ is reducible, then the splitting field does not have degree $n!$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I tried that as well, but I don't know how to pull it out, what theorems/facts do I need? Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Try out some examples. How big is the splitting field of a reducible polynomial of degree $3$? How about $4$?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan for $K=Q$, a polynomial of degree 3 may not have any roots in $\mathbb Q$, so the spliting field would be form at most by adjoining 2 of those roots, so the degree is at most 2, I am right?. For a 4-degree polynomial the degree is at most 3, I think by adjoining 3 of the 4 non rational roots in the worst case scenario

Comment: This post was a duplicate of [Degree of Splitting Field to Prove Irreducibility](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1134237), found [using Approach$0$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5BL%3AK%5D%3Dn!%24&p=1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose not, $f=gh$ with $\deg(g)=a$ and $\deg(h)=b=n-a$ where $a,b\ge1$.

Now let $K_1$ be the splitting field of $g$ over $K$. So $[K_1:K] \le a!$ and $[L:K_1]\le b!$. So $[L:K]\le a!b!$ which is strictly less than $n!$ if any of $a,b>1$.

**Edit 1**: $[K_1:K] \mid a! \implies [K_1:K]\le a!$ and ${n\choose k}>1 \iff k\ne0,n$.

Comment: Why does $[K_1:K]\le a!$?  amd how do you prove $a!b! <n! , for a>0 $ or $b>0$ ?

Comment: $\frac{n!} {a!b!} = {n \choose a}$

Comment: One should point out that $L$ is the splitting field of $h$ over $K_1$, and this is why  $[L:K_1]\le b!$.

Comment: +1, but this answer should be deleted, as a duplicate of [that one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1134254).

Comment: @user26857 Both should be done. It is recommended not to duplicate answers, but this post needs to be reopened in order to be re-closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Hi there. I have one unanswered question. Would you like to see this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2531008/subextension-of-a-field-with-galois-series-of-subextensions-of-prime-degree Thank you very much for your help!